# React-datepicker css customisation in dark mode using Tailwind CSS for calendar elements

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, darkmode, react-datepicker, tailwind-ui

I'm trying to customise react datepicker's inside elements(calendar, headers, nav buttons) in dark & light mode while using with Tailwind css?
In the below image- I'm looking to change css for those light coloured areas.

[image: dark mode datepicker]

I tried giving Tailwind's dark classes directly to Datepicker component--> doesn't work.
Tried applying css through global css file as below --> doesn't work

```
react-datepicker__time-list {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
@media screen and (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .react-datepicker__time-box,
  react-datepicker__time-list {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```

Is there is any className property I can apply to each components inside the Datepicker element for dark/light mode?
Can someone help me here?